# has how to get the user class? (ex: nitro classic, HypeSquad balance, etc)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Is there any way to get a user's class by command? I am creating a ''userinfo'' command and searched everywhere, I also tried some commands that related to ''class'' but without success

```
.setAuthor(member.user.tag)
    .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL())
    .addField("Member ID", member.id, true)
    .addField("Account", ` ${moment.utc(member.user.createdAt).format("DD, MMM YYYY")}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the [fetchFlags() method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=fetchFlags) on any user object. Resolve the promise and then call [toArray()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserFlags?scrollTo=toArray) on that UserFlags object. Your result will be an array of strings of user flags.